# Fixed Header/Footer + Content height 100% cause undesired vertical Scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to achieve a a horizontal scrolling website with a fixed header and footer.

Goals:
 1. Fixed Header and Footer
 2. No vertical scrolling 
 3. Content div fills all space between the header and footer

I used position: absolute on the content to make sure the height:100%  takes up the area between the header and the footer. (my third goal)
However this also causes a vertical scrollbar to appear.

live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wQ2XR/230/

how can i achieve my goals without a vertical scrollbar to appear?

thanks a lot in advance!

The html code:

```
    <div id="total">
        <header id="1">
            <div id="a">
                    <h1>Header</h1>

            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="2">
            <div id="b">
                <div id="bb">
                    <h2>Post Title Example One</h2> 
                <p>hello world! Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer id="3">
            <div id="c">
                    <h1>footer</h1>

            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

the css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
}

header {
}

#a {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

 #2 {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0 25px 0;
}

#b {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#bb {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

 footer {
}

#c {
    position: fixed;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm, the problem is that the wrapper(s) around your content between the header and footer are taking on the height of the viewport with `height:100%`. So, when you apply a margin to vertically offset those content wrappers (so that the header becomes visible), they get pushed by that much below the viewport (50px, height of the header). As a result, you get a vertical scrollbar, since the content wrappers are both the full height of the viewport *and* pushed down - so they can't fit on-screen.

How to avoid this? Well, if your footer and header height won't be dynamic (ie. You'll always be in control of how tall they are through your CSS), you can achieve this in a fairly straightforward manner with `position:absolute`.

Your structure I modified slightly; I removed the `#2` and `#b` elements, since it looks like they were just there to properly position/size `#bb`, the actual content-containing element:

```
<div id="total">
    <header id="1">
        <div id="a">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="bb">
        <h2>Post Title Example One</h2> 
        <p>hello world! Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?</p>
    </div>
    <footer id="3">
        <div id="c">
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Now, with your CSS, I removed the definitions for styling `#2` and `#b`. Additionally, I modified the `#bb` CSS to read as:

```
#bb {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 25px;
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ2XR/235/) to demonstrate what this achieves. Additionally, here's a [JSFiddle implementing your multiple-row layout](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ2XR/236/) which you gave as a comment in one of the answers.

The reason why `overflow:hidden` doesn't quite work is because `#bb` would actually still extend below the viewport - just, no vertical scrollbar would be created because that overflowing region is ignored by the browser. However, when you use a percentage height, it becomes apparent that the height of `#bb` is not that which is visible. Anyways, hope this helps out! If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Spot on! Thanks. Parallel with you i came up with the following solution. Which is in fact longer and different: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ2XR/237/. 
Working with padding (thus having to put 100% height on bb still) and having to remove the background colour. This only works though when you apply a border-box to bb as well. Do you know why this is (especially the border box)? Either way I will implement your solution since its shorter ;)

Comment: Glad I could help out! And that's an interesting solution using border-box. The reason why it works is because when setting `box-sizing:border-box` on `#bb`, it means that its padding gets figured into its height, so `height:100%` lets it be the height of the viewport, even with padding. When you put your `.row` elements in, the available height for them to expand to is the height of `#bb`, minus its padding. The padding of `#bb` is hidden behind the footer and header, while the `.row` elements expand to fill the space between them. Hope this was clear! Comments are a bit short for answers...

Comment: I get your explanation. That is clearly what it does. The name border box to me suggests that its a box around the border, so my gut tells me it puts a box outside the padding (where the border goes). The effective box that remains (after calling this in my css) is the box is everything inside the padding (like you mention). Clearly not what you would expect firsthand. I'm glad it works the way it does to be honest, it might come in handy some day. Thanks for your help! You saved the day.

Answer (score -2):

To hide the scrollbar use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

However, the text needs to go somewhere (otherwise it will be hidden), so you need to have the container larger or use text-columns.

Do you intend to achieve something like Windows 8 Metro UI for the scrolling?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your suggestion solved part of my problem but to show you the rest we have to dig a little deeper. 

I updated my example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ2XR/234/
<br>
As you can see i'm sort of going for the Metro style UI (you guessed right!) with 3 rows with the height set to 33%. The scrollbar is gone. But the bottom row, although it is set to height:33% in the css, wont space out with the other rows. 

Solving this would totally solve my problem! Do you have any clue how to do that?